# Adding changes or derivatives between two points

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, curves, infinitesimals

I've playing with the limit definition of derivative and I've to somewhat confusing conclusions.

To clarify, I'm from an Engineering background so I don't think that an instantaneous rate of change makes any sense, for it to be a rate of change something has to change, right?! 
So I think of derivatives as the ratio between a very small change in $y$ to a very small change in $x$. So It must be different at every point for many curves.

So I plugged in the formula to calculate the "ratio of change" between points $x+h$ and $x$

$\lim _{h\to \:0}\left(\frac{\left(x+h\right)^2-x^2}{x}\right) = 2x$

This is the expected answer

However If I try to plug in the points $x+6h$ and $x+5h$, both are distinct from $x+h$ and $x$, so at I expect to find a different answer but I found the same answer

$\lim _{h\to \:0}\left(\frac{\left(x+6h\right)^2-\left(x+5h\right)^2}{x}\right) = 2x$

It gets even more confusing If I try to compute the derivative between $x$ and a previous point $x-h$, it still gives me the same answer!

$\lim _{h\to \:0}\left(\frac{\left(x\right)^2-\left(x-h\right)^2}{x}\right) = 2x$

I can't make sense of it. It means If chose an arbitrary point $x = m$ then no matter how far I go far from it in any direction I get the same derivative which is quite patently wrong! If it is due to $h$ approaching zero, or it being an infinitesimal how then can we proceed from point to point if not by adding an infinitesimally lengthy line segment, or aren't all curves made up very small line segments?

I hope I made myself clear!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You’ve got a consistent error in all of your difference quotients: the denominator should be $h$.

Comment: I wanted to write h. My bad, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine the curve of an arbitrary function $f$. We can say that two points on the curve are $(x_1, f(x_1))$ and $(x_2, f(x_2))$

We can draw a straight line between these two points, and it's gradient is given by:

$$m=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$$
for *any* $x_1, x_2 \in \mathcal D(f)$ (the domain, essentially, wherever $f$ is defined)

We can assume that $x_2 > x_1$, or rather that $x_2 =x_1 +h$ for some arbitrary $h$ (In the case where it isn't, we can just switch $x_1$ and $x_2$ everywhere I've written them)

Then we have:

$$m=\frac{f(x_1+h)-f(x_1)}{x_1+h-x_1}=\frac{f(x_1+h)-f(x_1)}{h}$$

If $f(x)=x^2$, we have $m=\frac{(x_1+h)^2-x_1^2}{h}=\frac{h^2+2hx_1}{h}=2x_1+h$

What the derivative calculates is $m$ when $h$ is infinitesimal, that is, it measures the gradient between two points that are so close to each other they are basically the same point, and that forms the gradient of the tangent to $f$ at that point.

We *can* say that $$\lim_{h\to 0}{(2x_1+h)}=2x_1$$

In fact:

$$\lim_{h\to0} (kh)=0$$
is true for any constant $k$

and that is why the derivative always comes out as $2x$, because the $h$, and its multiples thereof, all disappear as the limit is taken to $0$.

Comment: But isn't it quite nonsensical to talk about a gradient at a point? What does it mean?

Comment: The gradient of the tangent to the curve at that point.

Comment: But how then the Gradient of the tangent to the curve tells us about change ALONG the curve? Don't we add these small changes to get from one point to another? Such as we do with integration?

Comment: For the first question, it tells us where the curve is about to go. For example, a negative derivative tells us the curve is about to decrease, and the quantity of that negative describes the scale (e.g. a derivative of $-5$ implies a much steeper descent than one of, say, $-2$).

Comment: For the second, no, you just calculate it from a different point. The reason why $2x$ was the derivative in all three cases was because $h \to 0 \implies kh \to 0 \forall k\in \Bbb R$. You were just adding multiples of $h$ in your other examples, hence they disappeared. With regards to integration, that finds the area under the curve between two points, and our approximation method for this, like the gradient method I described in my answer is an approximation for differentiation, is called the [Trapezoidal Rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule).

Comment: Yes. I get that the derivative is about a scale of change or something like this. For the second part my main problem is $f(x+h) - f(x)$ and $f(x) - f(x-h)$ will yield the same derivative. But the points $f(x+h) and f(x-h)$ I can interpret the first case from this point onward the rate of change is going to be 'something' and the second case I can't interpret it in a similar manner.

Comment: The first one gives a derivative of $\lim_{h\to 0}{(2x+h)}=2x$. I explained that in my answer. Similarly, substituting $x_1=x-h$, the second gives a derivative of $\lim_{h\to 0}{2(x-h)+h}=\lim_{h\to 0}{(2x-h)}=2x$.

Comment: I know how the computation works. I am interested in the interpretation! I don't get it in the second case.

Comment: You're only moving the point at which you take the derivative by a tiny amount, so it should end up the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct—you're just approaching $x$ in different ways as you take the limit. In the example with $f(x+6h)-f(x+5h)$ you're approximating the slope a little to the right of $x$, but as $h\rightarrow 0$ you still end up at $x$ and get the slope there—which turns out to be $2x$ as it should. You're deriving the same correct answer in different ways.

Comment: How can they be correct? How am I approaching the same point x? Then how can I define another point? How can I go from X0 to X1?

Comment: Isn't the interpretation of derivative is the rate of change between x and infinitesimally close point? Shouldn't they be different for each set if two points? What is the slope at a point? What is changing at a point which is a static entity?

Comment: @RaafatAbualazm It's nowadays very carefully *not* defined in terms of infinitesimal distances but as a limit—since a point can't have a slope. Geometrically, it's the slope of a tangent to the curve at the point. Another way to imagine it is that it's the direction you'd be facing if you were travelling along the curve—which you can define at each instant.

Comment: @RaafatAbualazm You're approaching $x$ each time because $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} (x+5h) =x$ just like $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} (x+h)=x$.

Comment: Then how can we reach point b from point a? Don't we add small changes to go from a to b? If that change is not along the curve of the function then how can the above reasoning and Integration hold?

Comment: In the derivation, $x$ is an unspecified fixed value throughout the argument. Because it's unspecified, once you've got the formula you know that you could have chosen $x=x_1$ (or $x=x_2$) and would have got $2x_1$ or ($2x_2)$ as the derivative

Comment: But now how can go from X1 to X2? I plug in X1 and now want to go to X2 from there. How can we go from here to there?

Comment: By "go from $a$ to $b$" do you mean "how does integrating the slope between them tell us how big $f(b)-f(a) $ is?

Comment: Yes. And more importantly how can slopebe  not along curve.

Comment: If derivative is just a slope of tangent not an infinitesimal change y due to an infinitesimal change in x.

Comment: @RaafatAbualazm I think the point is that if we made finite steps in the direction of the tangent, they would indeed lead us away from the curve—but the error becomes smaller as we reduce the size of the steps, and its *llimit* is zero—"if we could have infinitely short steps, they would follow the curve"—but the infinitely small steps can't actually exist (you can't go zero distance and go in a direction!)

Comment: @RaafatAbualazm Smaller steps take you along paths which approximate the curve more and more closely, and the curve is the limit of those paths.